# What does : public after struct mean?

Tags: c++, operating-system

```
    struct hpet : public description_table_header
{
    uint8_t hardware_rev_id;
    uint8_t comparator_count:5;
    uint8_t counter_size:1;
    uint8_t reserved:1;
    uint8_t legacy_replacement:1;
    pci_vendor_t pci_vendor_id;
    address_structure address;
    uint8_t hpet_number;
    uint16_t minimum_tick;
    uint8_t page_protection;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Why is there a public after the struct name and also `__attribute__((packed))`, why is packed inside paranthesis???
This is a table for a HPET(High Precision Event Timer).

Comment: I think it's `C++` ?

Comment: This is sturcture inheritance in C++. `packed` for structure alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is C++ and not C as you tagged it. That's quite an important detail.

The `public` here is the access specifier for the inheritance (the struct inherits from `description_table_header`). This will be covered in all good C++ textbooks. A relevant question here on SO is: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c). The specification of `public` for a `struct` is not actually needed since, for a struct, that is the default.

The `__attribute__((packed))` is a compiler specific extension that specifies the layout of the `struct`. In this case the `struct` is packed so that there is no padding in the struct.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a colon `:` followed by optional `public`/`private`/`protected` designator and a type name is the syntax for specifying inheritance.

In your code, the `hpet` class inherits the `description_table_header` class.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/860339/335858) for a discussion of the differences between public, private, and protected inheritance.

Comment: this is C++ (which is an excellent language for low level code) You struct is publically inheriting (which struct can do - the same way classes do)